# Can I continue shooting APS film if I think the roll isn't fully exposed?

Tags: film, point-and-shoot, aps

My new APS film says it is fully exposed after taking just one photo.

Can I continue shooting with it?

Comment: Can you explain more? What camera are you using? Where does it say that it is fully exposed? Are you talking about the little symbols on top of the film cassette? You know that you are not supposed to remove it from the camera right, until you've taken all the photos (unless taking advantage of "mid-roll rewind" feature, but then the cassette should show a symbol that it's partially used, not fully used).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you finding "new" rolls of APS? afaik, Fuji and Kodak stopped making APS film in 2011.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the APS film may have been previously exposed *except* for the final frame, then rewound into the cassette using the "mid-roll rewind" function that many APS cameras have. So when you loaded the cassette into your camera, it wound the film back to the spot from where it had been previously rewound. You exposed the final frame and then the film cassette notified the camera that it had been used up.